# Create form validation like Twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

How does Twitter create the form validation on it's [signup page](https://twitter.com/signup)?

[image]

I'm not creating a signup form, just an enquiries form which I would like to use the Twitter style validation.

Are there any specific tutorials or resources to create something very similar?

**Will this kind of validation stop spam to some degree?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are several.  [Here is a page](http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/17/10-useful-jquery-form-validation-techniques-and-tutorials-2/) that shows 10 jquery examples and tutorials.